# MySQL slow query logs not working

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I need some help diagnosing a fault

I have a development server and a production server. They are (in the large part) identical in setup. Both are Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS installs.

I turned on the MySQL slow query logs on both servers, and it works on the development server, but not the production server. On development, the slow query log fills up fairly quicly, but on production, the log file remains empty.

And idea how I can diagnose why it's not working on production? Are there any error logs that might contain the information?

There's nothing obviously relevant in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, and `/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log` actually exists - it's just empty.

my.cnf:

```
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
```

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: What value did you set `long_query_time` to? And how about the `min_examined_row_limit`? What query did you use to test?

Comment: `log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log, long_query_time = 2`, `min_examined_row_limit` is not set (on either server). I've run a few queries that took longer than 2 seconds.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you running?

Answer (score 2):

I'd check the MySQL server versions for the correct parameters to use, as there are differences between them.

E.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Which states that `log_slow_queries` is depracated as of version 5.1.29, and you need to use `slow_query_log = 1` to enable it and `slow_query_log_file = /path/to/file.name`

Prior to 5.1.29 you used `log_slow_queries = /path/to/file.name` to specify where to log the queries to.

Between 5.1.12 and 5.1.29 you could use either variant.

It could be that your production box is 5.1.29 or higher, and your dev box is pre-5.1.29 and can therefore understand the options you are using, and the production box can't...

Comment: How strange! Server versions are identical: "5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10-log (Ubuntu)", but the old style my.cnf was working on dev but not prod. I've updated both my.cnf's, dev still works - just need to wait until I can restart prod to see if it works... Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: The restart of the production server didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific on what is 'not working' Is it a system crash? A select not returning the right information? Tables not updating?

In general tools such as the:

explain statement (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

show process list (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html)

general query log  (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html)

are other avenues of investigation.

Comment: The slow-query log file just remains empty - like I never enabled it. I've updated my original question.